# Multiple Share variable in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am developing report to generate various PDF files. This report should mask certain data such as name ,address ,phone depending upon the parameter passed to report. This report has various sub reports (Transaction Statement, Balance Statement etc)

I have declare one flag which identifies whether data needs to be masked or not. Depending upon i am masking filed in the all Sub Reports. I know this is difficult to maintain as if there is any change in formula , it needs to be applied all the  sub reports. Hence I am looking for using shared variables which can be accessed in all sub reports. Can I create multiple share variables in the same formula (Name, Address etc) & pass them to all sub reports ?

Comment: Yes you alcan create multiple shared variables in a single formula and use across multiple sib reports

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a shared variable in a formula and it will be known in subreports.

For example, suppose you create a formula in your main report:

```
shared numbervar letsMask
shared numbervar anotherOne
letsMask := 1
anotherOne := 2
```

Then, you can reuse it in a formula in your subreport:

```
shared numbervar letsMask
shared numbervar anotherOne
if letsMask = 1 and anotherOne = 2 then "Print this, i bet it is true"
else "This will not happen"
```

Note there is no need to "pass" it to the subreport. The subreport is aware of the shared variables.